# Granting ClickOnce System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission permission?

Tags: permissions, clickonce

I'm having issues with the above permission not being set. The .NET ClickOnce deployment has been set as full trust. How can I ensure this permission is available - I thought it would be since it is full trust??

Is this possible? (The app works fine when running on desktop, just not through clickonce)

Thanks,
Ross.

Comment: I dont understand. Does your ClickOnce application install a web app?

Comment: I'm having the same problem (seems like the clickonce app needs the AspNetHostingPermission permission!) , did you manage to find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full trust does not mean administrative privileges. ClickOnce applications will not run with elevated privileges. So the question is would a user with no administrative privileges have that permission?

You can start a process that prompts for elevation, but you can't prompt for elevation successfully in a ClickOnce app. What I mean is if there's something specific that you are using that permission for, make a separate exe for it, and have the ClickOnce application do a process.start on it. Windows will prompt for elevation if needed, and then run it.